# 100% of page height app homescreen CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an app homescreen in CSS. Think of the layout of the iphone where you select the app. Basically a 3x2 grid that's 100% of the device page.

The problem I'm having is that this is used by lots of different devices so the height/width changes depending on the device.

The width is working fine, but the height is adding a scroll sometimes on some devices. Basically I want the page to go full screen on the app and have no scrolling.

Heres my HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="iconL">
            <img src="http://coloredwebdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/person-icon.png" />
        </div>
         <div class="iconR">
            <img src="http://coloredwebdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/person-icon.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="iconL">
            <img src="http://coloredwebdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/person-icon.png" />
        </div>
         <div class="iconR">
            <img src="http://coloredwebdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/person-icon.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="iconL">
            <img src="http://coloredwebdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/person-icon.png" />
        </div>
         <div class="iconR">
            <img src="http://coloredwebdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/person-icon.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Heres my CSS:

```
.outer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
}

.iconL {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.iconL img {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.iconR {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.iconR img {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

i've made a JSFilddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QrbKh/

As you can see it scrolls in there

Comment: So you want the three rows to fit on the screen without vertical scrolling, so each row is about 33.33% of the total/screen height? and the image width will scale accordingly?

Comment: Yeah basically, the icons will be quite big (to factor each device) and then the page to shirnk them accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The problem with percents is that they're always relative to the elements parent. If you take a look inside the Developer Tools you'll realise that .outer has an actual height of 0 (zero). That's because the body as .outer's parent has no height set which is interpreted as zero (100% of zero are still zero).
To solve that problem, just add

```
html,
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

to your CSS. That makes html and body fill the entire page.

Then add

```
.row {
    height:33.3%;
}

.iconL,
.iconR,
.iconL img,
.iconR img {
    height:100%;
}
```

That works fine for me. But since you can't divide 100 by 3 without a rest, also add

```
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Another solution could be using the viewport-values.

```
.row {
    height:33.3vh;
}
```

where "vh" stands for "viewport height". So 33.3vh refers to "1/3 of the viewports height". Actually the viewport-values have an acceptable support: http://caniuse.com/#search=viewport

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `max-height` to the `img` element. Is that what you want? 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrbKh/3/)

```
img {
max-height: calc(100%/3); // or 33.33%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following CSS may achieve what you need:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.outer{
    height: 100%;
}
.row {
    height: 33.333333333%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.iconL {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.iconL img {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.iconR {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: beige;
}
.iconR img {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

As stated earlier, you need to specify `height: 100%` to your `html` and `body` elements to set a reference value that can be inherited by the descendant elements.

The key is to scale the images to a height of 100% of the row height, which is set to 33.33% of the screen height.

Adding `vertical-align: top` to the images cleans up a sliver of whitespace below the baseline.

Since you only have two elements floated in the row, you can float both to the left or the left to the left and the right to the right.

Adding `overflow: hidden` to `.row` will keep the row's floats within their own block formatting context.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/ZYL2C/

In Firefox, the result looks like:

[image]

You can align the left image to the right and the right image to the left and add some right/left margin values to control the spacing between the images.  Your mark-up allows for quite a bit of flexibility in this design.

Comment: It seems to work for a second then flicks away to full screen again. I think it might be jquery mobile taking over? http://screencast.com/t/oF7kiXsYlVQN i've taken a video of the problem

Comment: Hey! cool video, nice! My first guess is that jQuery mobile has a style sheet with CSS rules that are over riding the ones you just created.  If this is the case, you would need to make your rules more specific, perhaps by adding an `id` and so on.  Also, look at any media queries that might be altering CSS settings.  I think we solved the CSS layout issue, now we need to solve the implementation/platform issue.